# Given $G$ is a finite group, $a$ and $b \in G$, $H\le G$, and $N=N(H)$, prove that if $aHa^{-1}=bHb^{-1}$, then $aN=bN$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, normal-subgroups

I am having difficulties proving the below statement:

> Given $G$ is a finite group, $a$ and $b \in G$, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $N=N(H)$, i.e. $N$ is the normalizer of $H$:
>
> If $aHa^{-1}=bHb^{-1}$, then $aN=bN$

I have generated four other pieces of information that I think may be useful:

1. $N(H) < G$
2. $H \subset N(H)$
3. $H \lhd N(H)$
4. $b^{-1}a \in N(H)$

I would like to structure this proof in to two sections; one that shows $aN \subseteq bN$ and one that shows $bN \subseteq aN$ (presumably without any loss of generality from the former section).

I have a hunch that an important part of this proof is recognizing that $n_1\circ H \circ n_1^{-1}$, where $n_1$ and $n_1^{-1} \in N$, is the same set as $H$...but I cannot quite figure out how to set it up.

Cheers.

Comment: for any subgroup $K\le G$ and any $a,b\in G$ you can show $b^{-1}a\in K$ if and only if $bK=aK$, so your facts 1 and 4 suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statements are equivalent:

$$aHa^{-1}=bHb^{-1}$$
$$b^{-1}aHa^{-1}b=H$$
$$b^{-1}aH(b^{-1}a)^{-1}=H$$
$$b^{-1}a\in N$$
$$aN=bN$$

Comment: How do you conclude the last line? Is there a "subproof" that you could link me to?

Comment: In general, if $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $x,y\in G$, then you can show that $y^{-1}x\in H$ iff $xH=yH$.

Comment: Given a group $G$, a subgroup $H$, and elements $x,y\in H$. We can prove that $y^{-1}x\in H$ iff $xH=yH$ as follows: first note that $xH=yH$ iff $y^{-1}xH=H$. For any $h\in H$, $hH=H$, so if $y^{-1}x\in H$, then $y^{-1}xH=H$. Conversely, suppose that $y^{-1}xH=H$. Note that $y^{-1}x\cdot1\in y^{-1}xH$, so $y^{-1}x\cdot1\in H$. So $y^{-1}x\in H$. $\square$

Comment: Great! Therefore, is a corollary of this proof that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the number of unique conjugates of $H$ and the number of unique cosets of $N$?

Comment: Yes, your corollary is correct. In general, if we let $G$ act on its subgroups by conjugation, then the stabilizer of a subgroup is the normalizer of that subgroup. And the elements of the orbit of a subgroup are just the conjugates of that subgroup. Elements of an orbit of an element correspond to left-cosets of the stabilizer of that element. So conjugates of a subgroup correspond to left-cosets of the normalizer of that subgroup.

Comment: If you're still up for it, rather than opening a new thread to post a question, the bijective function that confirms this is the following, correct? $f(aHa^{-1})=aN_{(H)}$

Comment: That's correct. It has been shown now that $aHa^{-1}=bHb^{-1}$ iff $aN=bN$. So the function is well-defined and one-to-one. Surjectivity also follows immediately, so the function is a bijection.